# Gatsby ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error how to solve?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

[image]

OS: window 10

I am making a blog using gatsby. During the production process, I changed the gatsby-config.js file as follows, but an error similar to the picture occurred.

[before]

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
      options: {
        isTSX: true,
        allExtensions: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    // {
    //   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    //   options: {
    //     name: `contents`,
    //     path: `${__dirname}/contents`,
    //   },
    // },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: <https://gatsby.dev/offline>
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
};
```

[after]

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
      options: {
        isTSX: true,
        allExtensions: true,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `contents`,
        path: `${__dirname}/contents`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-smartypants',
            options: {
              dashes: 'oldschool',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-prismjs',
            options: {
              classPrefix: 'language-',
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
            options: {
              maxWidth: 768,
              quality: 100,
              withWebp: true,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files',
            options: {},
          },
          {
            resolve: 'gatsby-remark-external-links',
            options: {
              target: '_blank',
              rel: 'nofollow',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I tried various solutions through Google.

node fetch reinstall, package.json 's type = module change

No effort was successful.

They say it's an import problem, but I don't know why it suddenly became an import problem.